# Dynamically creating dataframes from csv files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I'm trying to dynamically create dataframes depending on the amount of unique values i get in one column.
i have managed to create a dictionary kontaining key and an empty df.
I have also managed to sort it out so that i can access the data that i want to put in each df.

now my problem is that i cant sew it´togheter and fill the empty df with the data i get from the grouped variable.

any suggestions on how i solve this or why this is not working?
i have the imports that i need but i skipped to share it..

```
pd.read_csv("transaktioner_2013-01-01_2021-04-14.csv", sep=";")
# Finding different accounts
konton = df1["Konto"].unique()
# Create a dict with elements for each account
grouped = df1.groupby(df1.Konto)
lst = []
for group in grouped:
    lst.append(group)
konto_dict = {}
i = 0
for konto in konton:
    konto_dict[konto] = pd.DataFrame()
    konto_dict[konto] = konto_dict[konto].append(grouped.get_group(lst[i]))
    i += 1
print(konto_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this after some tinkering. So if anyone want to dynamically create a dictionary containing dataframes the following code works for me.

```
df1= pd.read_csv("transaktioner_2013-01-01_2021-04-14.csv", sep=";")

# Finding different accounts
konton = df1["Konto"].unique()
# Create a dict with elements for each account
grouped = df1.groupby(df1.Konto)

konto_dict = {}
i = 0
for konto in konton:
    konto_dict[konto] = pd.DataFrame(grouped.get_group(konto))
```